# Spring not accepting embedded json

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson, abstraction

I am stuck with a JSON and need assistance for the same.

I've a JSON like below which I'm getting from client. i'm using Chrome rest client to pass parameters.The content-type is "application/json"

My controller and bean classes are below. When I am making a post call I'm getting 400 bad request error.Please let me what is wrong? Is there any other way to implement apart from using so many bean classes?

```
{
    "addSurveyRequest": {
        "data": {
            "suveyName": "abcde",
            "surveyDesc": "pqrst",
            "surveyFromDate": "MM-DD-YYYY",
            "surveyToDate": "MM-DD-YYYY",
            "surveyOptions": [
                {
                    "surveyOptionName": "abc",
                    "surveyOptionDesc": "qwerty"
                },
                {
                    "surveyOptionName": "pqr",
                    "surveyOptionDesc": "asdfg"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I've my controller like

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/json", produces="application/json")
public @ResponseBody String addSurvey(@RequestBody AddSurveyRequest addSurveyRequest) throws Exception
{
    String surveyId=null;
    logger.debug("surveyName"+addSurveyRequest.getDataDTO().getSurveyDTO().getSurveyName()+"surveyDesc "+addSurveyRequest.getDataDTO().getSurveyDTO().getSurveyDesc()+"fromdate"+addSurveyRequest.getDataDTO().getSurveyDTO().getSurveyFromDate());
}
```

I've my bean class like below.

```
public class AddSurveyRequest{
    private DataDTO data;
    //setteres and getters
}

public class DataDTO{
    private SurveyDTO surveyDTO;
    //setteres and getters
}

public class SurveyDTO {
    private int surveyId;
    private String surveyName;
    private String surveyDesc;  
    private Date surveyFromDate;
    private Date surveyToDate;
    private List<SurveyOptionDTO> surveyOptions;
    //setteres and getters
}

public class SurveyOptionDTO {
    private String surveyOptionName;
    private String surveyOptionDesc;
    //setteres and getters
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: error 400 happens in most cases when Your URL is invalid (not mapped by the controller)

Comment: You could try `addSurvey(@RequestBody String jsonString)` and then do whatever processing you need on your own

Comment: If I accept it as a String, how will I get the value of individual keys later?

Comment: @akfaz there is no issue with the URL, because if I accept the parameters using Map<String, Object>, it works perfectly fine

Comment: You need to post the error log from your server, but the most likely cause is that the main element is "wrapped" (the root JSON object isn't your DTO, it's a map of the name to your DTO). There are a few ways to resolve that, but let's see first whether that's the issue. It could also that you're actually sending form encoding, which is the default with POST.

Answer (score 1):

I would say you should change the JSON input removing the outer `addSurveyRequest` as you declared the `AddSurveyRequest` type as parameter:

```
{
    "data": {
        "suveyName": "abcde",
        "surveyDesc": "pqrst",
        "surveyFromDate": "MM-DD-YYYY",
        "surveyToDate": "MM-DD-YYYY",
        "surveyOptions": [
            {
                "surveyOptionName": "abc",
                "surveyOptionDesc": "qwerty"
            },
            {
                "surveyOptionName": "pqr",
                "surveyOptionDesc": "asdfg"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made the variable name's in my Java class same as JSON parameter name and it worked out for me. I got this answer from another link, missed the link.

Below are the changes I made and it worked!

`public class AddSurveyRequest{
    private DataDTO addSurveyRequest;
    //setteres and getters
}`

`public class DataDTO{
    private SurveyDTO data;
    //setteres and getters
}`